# How to convert a JSON document to Java (parse integer numbers only)

Tags: json, jsonparser

I have searched everywhere and i can't seem to find a solution OR youtube video. Has anyone done this before? Any suggestions on how to go about this please.

Comment: Maybe follow a training about searching ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**>     Example JSON:**

```
{
   "value":1
}


int z = jsonObject.getInt("value");
```